# Previous Craigslist Postings

Tags: data-request, web-crawling

Is there a way to access previous craigslist postings in bulk? Particularly interested in being able to select certain categories and download all listings at certain time periods for that category.

Or am I better off just crawling and slowly building the required data set over time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Internet Archive's [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) to retrieve old Craigslist pages.

For example, capture dates:

```
http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/ats
```

And one archived page:

```
http://web.archive.org/web/20150113174952/http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/ats
```

All of these links go to archived listings. For example:

```
http://web.archive.org/web/20150113185626/http://sfbay.craigslist.org/sby/ats/4841850048.html
```

---

Instead of screen-scraping, there is an [API](https://archive.org/help/wayback_api.php), which makes the process of finding archive dates for individual pages.

> This simple API for Wayback is a test to see if a given url is archived and currenlty accessible in the Wayback Machine.

Here is a [small python script](https://gist.github.com/philshem/9504719) to access the API.

The good thing about Craigslist is that one you give the host-name (i.e. **sfbay**.craigslist.org), the rest of the URL structure should be similar. You can also scrape the main page to get all the host-names (sfbay, newyork, etc).

You'll find a complete list of categories sites on the CL [bulk loading page](http://www.craigslist.org/about/bulk_posting_interface).

---

Other ideas:

- Rework an [unofficial API](https://github.com/mohislm/craigslist-api) to use the Wayback machine URL
- [Use the RSS feed from CL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10353131/2327328)

---

For other ideas, take a look at these questions from StackOverflow

- [2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/237124/2327328)
- [2010](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3633830/2327328)
- [2012](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10353021/2327328)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use the API suggested by Programmable web, including that of Craigslist bulk posting, 3Taps etc?

https://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/apis?keyword=craigslist

Answer (score 0):

You could also use https://clippings.june07.com/, it's open source:

blog: https://june07.com/introduction-clippings/